# using the for words like father or mother or cousin or brother

Tags: word-usage

i wanted to ask you if in a novel there is a family, and we want not to mention
the name of characters_ for exam in a room characters are members of family_ should we use the word "the" before the name just conveys their position in family, for exam, father said," i'm tired." mother got into the room. cousin helped her to wash the dishes. this way of writing is true or using "the" behind them is necessary

Comment: Usually you'd say **x's** father/mother/brother/cousin

Comment: Without the article, the sentence is usually not complete and so not grammatical. When referring to one's own father/mother/etc., the article is not needed.

Comment: This question would suit better on [Writing Stack Exchange](https://writing.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Broadly, Kakoo, no; you can't say that.

Nigel's Writing Stack Exchange would clearly be better, as might English Language Learners.

By the way please be very, very carful about what Kris suggested.